# How to run files from every folder in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a main folder project name `socialNetwork`. In this folder, I have 3 folder name `application`, `database`, and `view`. folder `view` has 2 folders `views` and `page`. These folders have files php. Now if I want to run the file from `view` folder I have to be in`PSC:\PhpstormProject\socialNetwork\>` and use `php view/page/profile.php`. If I run `PSC:\PhpstormProject\socialNetwork\view>` and use `php page/profile.php` show me the error `Could not open input file: page/profile.php`. So what can I do to run files from every folder, because now I can only from the main project folder?

Comment: You talk about `pages` folder but in your code you talk about `page`. Without going any further, there is already a problem, isn't it...?

Comment: @Juan I improve my post, that was typo

Comment: OK. And if you write this `./page/profile.php` instead of `page/profile.php` ...?

Comment: That's not working, show the same error

Comment: And with this code `__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'page'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'profile.php';`...?